# Remove strings of mixed letters and numbers

Tags: regex, gsub

I have a data frame with a column containing character strings.  I want to remove all 'words' that contain mixtures of letters and numbers (e.g. 'T6YUIFG8', '898CC'....these 'words' are three characters or more in length).  They only use upper case letters, but otherwise are unrestricted, and don't follow any other rules.  How can I remove them without the surrounding text using gsub in R?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try anything yet? Please share what you have come up so far. Also, a sample input text would help.

Comment: @Neijwiert: No, it won't work since it will remove words like `NASA`.

Comment: Haven't managed to come up with any sensible suggestions yet as I don't know how to specify the 'randomness' of these codes!  Still working on it...

Comment: Are they surrounded by anthing else? Like `SomeParameter=VALUE`

Comment: I think I've found a 'rule' of sorts for these codes: they seem to occur in recurring lengths of 8, 4, 4, 4, 12 (e.g. "89FC8B93 7857 408D A004 45A35B19B509"), if that helps?  I'm really stuck on this one! Thanks

Comment: Please update the question with these requirements. Note that `7857` contains only digits. You might remove a valid 4-digit number if you just use regex without specifying specific requirements for 4-digit numbers. Also, previous examples in your question (*'T6YUIFG8', '898CC'*) do not meet the new criteria. The question is becoming even more unclear.

Comment: I don't know about gsub's regex's, and what they can do, but this pattern seems to match what you are looking for: `((U|D)*(DU|UD)(U|D)*){3,}` where D is a digit and U is an uppercase letter.

Comment: Maybe this one then. Assuming the second group is always numbers: `[A-Z0-9]{8} [0-9]{4} [A-Z0-9]{4} [A-Z0-9]{4} [A-Z0-9]{12}` Otherwise `[A-Z0-9]{8} [A-Z0-9]{4} [A-Z0-9]{4} [A-Z0-9]{4} [A-Z0-9]{12}`

Comment: Thanks all, Neijwiert's answer cracked it.

Comment: Posted as answer to close question.

Comment: @user4575913: please mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the second group contains only numbers use:

`[A-Z0-9]{8} [0-9]{4} [A-Z0-9]{4} [A-Z0-9]{4} [A-Z0-9]{12}`

Otherwise:

`[A-Z0-9]{8} [A-Z0-9]{4} [A-Z0-9]{4} [A-Z0-9]{4} [A-Z0-9]{12}`